# selenium python нажать на выпадающий список

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

Проблема такая, мне нужно нажать на кнопку ... (это у меня получается). После чего мне необходимо выбрать элемент по тексту в нем. Я думал это очень просто, но у меня не вышло, я получил xpath элемента и пытаюсь нажать на него после нажатия на кнопку ... Однако, я сваливаюсь в ошибку, что такой элемент не найден.

```
SELECT = ('xpath', '//*[@id="dropdownMenuLink"]')
MY_OPTION = ('xpath', '/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/button[6]')

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element(*SELECT).click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element(*MY_OPTION).click()
time.sleep(3)
```

[image][image: html код элементов]

Comment: Ссылку на страницу можете разместить?

Comment: @СергейКох не могу там доступ только после авторизации по оплаченному аккаунт

Comment: Этот выпадающий список не находиться в новом окне или в iframe? Если так, то сначала надо перевести фокус на него, а затем искать нужный элемент.